# How to keep activated sludge viable for a week?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, biotechnology

I am working in biological waste water treatment and I need to collect some activated sludge samples and have them characterized through different methods. The characterization will take from a few days to a week. How do I keep the sludge viable in this time? How do I make sure the bacteria do not die?

Comment: What about cooling these samples to 4°C?

Comment: I though about that as well, but ... I do not know if it is enough. I was thinking about aerating them and feeding some... yeast extract now and then? I don't know. That;s why I am asking the experts. :D

Comment: @Pompilia activated sludge would have different kinds of microbes and the general yeast-extract based media may not be suitable for all the microbes. Therefore, I think 4°C cooling may be a better option.

Comment: @WYSIWYG It is also the simplest method, so I'm fine with that. 

Let's see if someone suggests something else.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this review: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123914538, it discusses the issue of mass-producing organisms in a more general sense (i.e. not just bacteria)